# What did "make love" mean in the 1920s?

Tags: verbs, nouns, meaning-in-context

[This 1921 article](http://books.google.com/books?id=VvlHAQAAIAAJ&pg=PR33) gives "Ten Pointers for Domestic Happiness".

Pointer V reads:

> Make love to your wife; continue to be her sweetheart. Neglect begets indifference that is fatal to married life. Every true wife expects to be a sweetheart, and rightly. More than bitter disappointment follows disillussionment.

Did "make love" here just mean "be loving; be nice; etc."?

Comment: Language hasn't changed *that* much since then. A good dictionary should help you.

Comment: My favorite example of the change in meaning is the Cole Porter song [*Mind If I Make Love To You?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpQIZEcpypI)  Cole Porter was daring in many ways - but I cannot believe that he intended it as a direct synonym for "have sex with".  (The song was written in 1956, and your question is about the 1920s - but I believe the change in meaning came about in the 1960s; more research is required.)

Comment: To clarify: I think that "make love to" has always had a hint of sensuality about it; making love (in the older sense) may or may not lead to (or include) sexual intercourse.  From Samuel Pepys' Diary: "He told me... of Mrs. Stewart's going away from Court... and believes her... to be as virtuous as any woman in the world: and told me... that when the Duke of Richmond did **make love to her**, she did ask the King..."  (shortened for length - Pepys could go on and on.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the early 1500's until perhaps the mid-1900's, the following sense of *make love* was common:

> (now archaic) To make amorous approaches to; to woo, romance, court.

To illustrate this sense, [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_love) provides five quotations, dated from 1501 through 1946.  For example:

> **1815**, Jane Austen, *[Emma](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/158/158-h/158-h.htm#link2HCH0015)*:
>   scarcely had she begun, scarcely had they passed the sweep-gate and joined the other carriage, than she found her subject cut up – her hand seized – her attention demanded, and Mr. Elton actually making violent love to her: availing himself of the precious opportunity, declaring sentiments which must already be well known [...].

In the referenced scene, Emma and Mr. Elton are riding in a closed carriage after a Christmas entertainment; Mr. Elton takes hold of Emma's hand and begins telling her of his “ardent attachment” and “unequalled love” for her.  That is, he is making amorous advances, wooing, romancing, courting; and no more than that.

The advice mentioned in the question – to “Make love to your wife; continue to be her sweetheart” – does not suggest sex per se, but instead suggests wooing, romancing, courting.

Comment: I can personally vouch that it was a common phrase up into the 1970's. I know its fallen out of fashion since, but I didn't realize it had gotten so bad that younger folks would have no clue what it meant. That's sad.

Answer (score 2):

Per @medica's comment, *a good dictionary should help you*. So here's the relevant bit from OED...

> **to make love** (under **love** noun, Phrase sense 3 b)
>    orig. U.S.  *To engage in sexual intercourse, esp. considered as an act of love. Freq. with to, with.*

...for which their ***first*** citation is...

> **1927** J. S. Bolan Deposition in L. Schlissel 3 Plays Mae West (1997) 218
>    *Jimmy embraces Margie LaMont and goes through with her the business of **making love** to her by lying on top of her on a couch, each embracing the other.* <s>1</s>

Realistically, there's no chance that the writer of OP's 1921 citation would have expected readers to understand *make love = have sexual intercourse*. He just meant *be loving and attentive, as you were when you were courting*.

---

<s>1</s> There's some [discussion here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.usage.english/gqaB5CNUNf0/2LmRrkQerQwJ) about that "first citation" (i.e. - Why is it both 1927 *and* 1997?, and How do we *know* they weren't just cuddling/snogging?)

Comment: If the OED cites a work for which they do not have the original source, but have a later work which cites the earlier one, this is how they present it. So the 1927 J. S. Bolan Deposition was quoted in L. Schlissel's book "3 Plays by Mae West", and this is how the OED knows about it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to put the question is whether *to make love (to)*, which we know to be a euphemism for *to have sex (with)*, has always meant that. That meaning is actually very new, much newer than the expression itself.

For more than four hundred years, *to make love (to)* had a more “courtly” meaning: “to pay amorous attention (to)”, “to court, woo”, according to the 1908 printing of the *New English Dictionary* (NED). Typical examples given in that work:

> **1605** [SHAKS.] *Macb.* III. i. 124 Thence it is That I to your assistance doe make loue.
>   **1768** STERNE *Sent. Journ.* (1775) You have been making love to me all this while.

The authors conclude that the English phrase was inspired by the French *faire l'amour* and Italian *far l'amore*.

So the sentence in the example means:

> [*Woo/court*] your wife; continue to be her sweetheart.

This is not to say that the word *love* cannot refer to sexual gratification. In fact, there are both well-known examples where it means exactly that:

> **1611** BIBLE *Prov.* vii. 18 Come, let vs take our fill of loue vntill the morning.

and well-known examples where it does not:

> **1611** BIBLE *Dan.* i. 9 God had brought Daniel into fauour and tender loue with the Prince of the Eunuches.

Conclusion: it’s not the word *love*, but the Romance-language-derived set phrase *to make love (to)*, that has recently acquired a specific meaning of sexual gratification: a meaning which rapidly eclipsed its traditional, more “courtly” meaning.